# Please help identity this "Ventoux" MTB

Tags: mountain-bike, identify-this-bike

Can anyone identify the maker, I’m guessing Ventoux is the model?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I see a late 2000's MTB of decent quality, or an early 2010s bike of medium quality.

Reasons:

- The wheels are 26" and while there's nothing wrong with them, more modern MTBs moved toward larger wheels.
- Disk brakes - a low end bike would have still had rim brakes.
- Fork stanchions are bare - the lack of covering boots shows the front suspension is moderately modern.

The rear rack implies a commuter or road usage, and that the saddle is lower than the bars supports a more upright position for comfort not aggressive MTB.

Also, there's a significant number of spacers under the stem, so its intentionally high at the front.

The tyres argue against having a lot of mileage on the road - they appear to be full knobblies, which are unpleasant to ride on tarmac for significant distances or speeds.

Brakes look like they are cable actuated - I can see bare inners on the top tube, whereas hydraulic brakes would have hoses.

The frame isn't coming up well in the photo - it could be steel with a clear laquer, or aluminium with clearcoat, or it could even be a titanium frame (though this is unlikely.)

The groupset is a triple chainring and probably 7/8/9 speeds at the rear.  That it is in the grannie ring suggests whoever last rode it was slow and relaxed.

---

A bit of googling shows that "ventoux" is a region in southern France with a well-known climb and appears in a lot of results.

I did find a bike shop in Australia but they appear to be a reseller and not a brand of bike.  However you might choose to make enquiries there in case they can advise.   **https://www.ventouxcycles.com.au/**

Comment: Thanks Criggie, good spots  the double meaning on the name makes it tricky to research, brings up too many geographical results! Impressed with your URL find, I didn’t get that far. I’ve requested more photos from the seller so will upload shortly, the square chainstay is interesting, suggests quality, yes the cable callipers aren’t a great sign but looking forward to finding out about the gears & forks, back soon...

Comment: I think either wheels were replaced or disk brakes were added at some point since there's a braking track on rims.

Comment: And there are v-brake mounts on the frame and not on the fork - so I guess the fork has been changed too

Comment: Sorry for comment spam - but I've looked closer and there are spacers under the stem - that makes me more confident that the fork is new to this frame

Comment: At the time when disc brakes were not default at all price points it wasn't uncommon on mid tier frames and wheels to have options for and equip the bike with one or other depending on price point.